# How websites recommend apps

Tags: ios

I'm wondering how websites like [target.com](https://www.target.com.au/) recommend an app at the top of the page on Apple devices.

[image: Picture of app recommendation]

How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is smart banners. Please check out the [official documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

> Smart App Banners vastly improve users’ browsing experience compared to other promotional methods. As banners are implemented in iOS 6, they will provide a consistent look and feel across the web that users will come to recognize.